# Plotly Express customdata not substituted on hovertext

Tags: plotly-express

New to plotly express, so go easy with me?

Trying to create a plot with some hover text for some lines:

```
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace( go.Scatter( y=ChartData["time50"], name="50% All", line=dict(color="#aecfd1"), fillcolor="#aecfd1", fill='tozeroy' )) # fill down to xaxis
    fig.add_trace( go.Scatter( y=ChartData["time95"], name="95% All", line=dict(color="#bed9da"), fillcolor="#bed9da", fill='tonexty' ))
    fig.add_trace( go.Scatter( y=ChartData["time99"], name="99% All", line=dict(color="#cee2e3"), fillcolor="#cee2e3", fill='tonexty' ))
    fig.add_trace( go.Scatter( y=ChartData["US Max Wait"],     name="US Max Wait",     line=dict(color="#dd3737"), customdata=ChartData['Datetime'] )) 
    fig.add_trace( go.Scatter( y=ChartData["Non US Max Wait"], name="Non US Max Wait", line=dict(color="#6f4c1e"), customdata=ChartData['Datetime'] )) 
    fig.update_layout( xaxis_title="", yaxis_title="Minutes waiting", legend_title_text='')
    fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
    fig.update_traces(
        hovertemplate="<br>".join([
            #"ColX: %{x}",
            "%{y} minutes wait",
            "%{customdata[0]}"
            ])
        )
```

but the hovertext for customdata for "US Max Wait" and "Non US Max Wait" isn't getting substituted:

[image]

Yet when I use px.line, it's fine:

```
    fig = px.line( ChartData, 
                  y=['US Max Wait', 'Non US Max Wait'],
                  custom_data=['Datetime'],
                  markers=True
                  )
```

[image]